# Connection To The Database Failed in DNN

Tags: database, database-connection, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

I am trying to install DotNetNuke, I created a virtual machine with Window Server 2008, and followed the video series to install DotNetNuke.

When I run the InstallerWizard I am getting this error: "Connection To The Database Failed"

Note that when I didn't find the account iss apppol/dnndev.me so I added my virtual login account as a database owner, I even created an account but still nothing.

I am frustrated with this, I've spent 3 days trying to solve it, as I don't know a lot in IIS.

Comment: How are you configuring SQL Server? Express or are you connecting to an existing DB?

Comment: when i opened SQL studio manager i will get WIN-O10UIAC9FNG\SQLEXPRESS in the server name which the first one is my machine name, and then i created a DB and add the account as an owner to this DB

Comment: i removed this account and added  NETWORK SERVICE for all the application pool and Site folder and as a database owner, the page is loaded first part only in database part i getting error Database Connection Error

Comment: Can you post the connection string from your web.config? (Just make sure it doesn't include any passwords or public IP addresses).

Comment: i tried to modify the connection string in site web.config, but still i am getting the connection error, i changed it as follow, <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 Express -->
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|dnndev.me.mdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

is that write?? note that my DB name is dnndev.me

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to setup using SQL server express? In case of express version, I suggest you setup AppPool identity as ApplicationPoolIdentity and have "Load User Profile" as "True".

Comment: thank you for the reply, but where can i setup the AppPool Identity?

Comment: Check the APPLICATION POOL in IIS to see what account it is running under

Comment: its running under ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: i changed it to NETWORK SERVICE account

Comment: When you are having AppPool Identity - you will need to have correct folder permissions. Executed following from command prompt ------ icacls C:\MyWebSitePath /grant "IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPoolName":(OI)(CI)(F)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error when I was trying to set up the website locally. Mine was due to the user identity in the Application Pool was wrong. This is what I did to solve it:

1) In IIS, go to your site, click on Basic Settings, or Advanced Settings, and find the Application Pool name.

2) In IIS, under Application Pools tree branch on the left, select your site's Application Pool, and click on it.

3) Click on Advanced Settings, then click on Identity. Set the account's user name and Password.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Application Pool Identity as **NetworkService**

Open IIS (Run-> inetmgr) and follow the steps from screenshot below.

[IIS -> Change Application Pool Indentity for DNN Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2d8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

No . this 2024 and when you see that Error ,it means you have to download SQL Express. it fixes the issue